# Issue with changing login shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, zsh

I want to change the default login shell on my Ubuntu.
To change the shell I ran the following:

```
$ chsh -s /usr/bin/zsh
```

After that I restart my terminal but my default shell is still bash.

```
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
```

These are shells installed on my machine:

```
$ cat /etc/shells
# /etc/shells: valid login shells
/bin/sh
/bin/dash
/bin/bash
/bin/rbash
/bin/zsh
/usr/bin/zsh
```

Record for my user in /etc/passwd is also changed like expected:

```
$ cat /etc/passwd|grep myuser
myuser:x:1000:1000:myuser,,,:/home/myuser:/usr/bin/zsh
```

I successfully changed my login shell the same way on my mac but I seem to be having some issue on Ubuntu. Am I missing something here?

Comment: What do you mean by "After I restart my terminal"? Could this terminal have a setting or profile or configuration that explicitly refers to bash? Is the login shell changed when you go to the console (e.g. `CTRL-ALT-F1` and then login on the text-mode console)?

Comment: @LarsFischer I just close the terminal and open it again. And Im expecting it to be zsh. And btw, if I do ctrl+alt+F1 then I get zsh. But not when I start the default terminal app in Ubuntu. Where could this configuration file be that causes this? ~/.profile or /etc/profile maybe?

Comment: you need to logout and log back into Ubuntu, Ctrl+Alt+F[1-6] represent 6 virtual shells while GUI login is on Ctrl+Alt+F7

Comment: Congratulations: you have successfully changed the login shell :) as you have seen on the textmode. Where the terminal application does its configuration? I have no idea, but I would have a look in its menu. For example KDE Konsole has it under Settings -> Manage Profiles and there is the `command` setting.

Comment: @ritesht93 logging out and into Ubuntu solved this, thanks!

Comment: Please mark it solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to logout and log back into Ubuntu so that your GUI based X terminal shells pick up the new shell value.

Note: Ctrl+Alt+F[1-6] represent 6 virtual shells while GUI login is on Ctrl+Alt+F7